# Average a subset of a matrix in a loop in matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, matrix, mean, subset

I work with an image that I consider as a matrix.

I want to turn a 800 x 800 matrix (A) into a 400 x 400 matrix (B) where the mean of 4 cells of the A matrix = 1 cell of the B matrix (I know this not a right code line) :

```
B[1,1] =mean2(A[1,1 + 1,2 + 2,1 + 2,2])
```

and so on for the whole matrix ...

```
B [1,2]=mean2(A[1,3 + 1,4 + 2,3 + 2,4 ])
```

I thought to :

1) Reshape the A matrix into a 2 x 320 000 matrix so I get the four cells I need to average next to each other and it is easier to deal with the row number afterwards.

```
Im4bis=reshape(permute(reshape(Im4,size(Im4,2),2,[]),[2,3,1]),2,[]);
```

2) Create a cell-array with the 4 cells I need to average (subsetted) and calculate the mean of it. That's where it doesn't work

```
I{1,160000}=ones,
for k=drange(1:2:319999)
    for n=1:160000
        I{n}=mean2(Im4bis(1:2,k:k+1));
    end
end
```

I created an empty matrix of 400 x 400 cells (actually a vector of 1 x 160000) and I wanted to fill it with the mean but I get a matrix of 1 x 319 999 cells with one cell out of 2 empty.

Looking for light

**My Input Image:**

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Method 1**

Using [`mat2cell`](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mat2cell.html) and [`cellfun`](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cellfun.html)

```
AC = mat2cell(A, repmat(2,size(A,1)/2,1), repmat(2,size(A,2)/2,1));

out = cellfun(@(x) mean(x(:)), AC);
```

**Method 2**

using [`im2col`](http://in.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/im2col.html)

```
out = reshape(mean(im2col(A,[2 2],'distinct')),size(A)./2);
```

**Method 3**

Using <s>simple</s> `for` loop

```
out(size(A,1)/2,size(A,2)/2) = 0;
k = 1;
for i = 1:2:size(A,1)
    l = 1;
    for j = 1:2:size(A,2)
        out(k,l) = mean(mean(A(i:i+1,j:j+1)));
        l = l+1;
    end
    k = k+1;
end
```

**Test on input image:**

```
A = rgb2gray(imread('inputImage.png'));

%// Here, You could use any of the method from any answers 
%// or you could use the best method from the bench-marking tests done by Divakar
out = reshape(mean(im2col(A,[2 2],'distinct')),size(A)./2);  

imshow(uint8(out));  

imwrite(uint8(out),'outputImage.bmp');
```

**Output Image:**

[image]

Final check by reading the already written image

```
B = imread('outputImage.bmp');

>> whos B

Name        Size              Bytes  Class    Attributes

B         400x400            160000  uint8
```

Comment: Nice approach, very clean

Comment: Thanks and you too as usual :) @LuisMendo

Comment: All the 3 methods are giving me same result, a 400 x 400 matrix in the matlab workspace but a 574 x 495 pixel images when I sace it as BMP. So, this is the same issue as the methods proposed by @Luis Mendo. I do not know what is the difference between the matrix size and image size ?? I know I need 400 x 400 pixels/cells because I will compute this image.

Comment: Moreover, I found that the result is not as I expected. My initial image is a fractal black/white image so I would guess that when we average 4 pixels, I would get a gray image, isn't ? I read something about the type of image, the difference could come from the fact that it is a 1 - 0 image and not a 255 - 0 ?

Comment: @Sarahdata Give us "whos(A)" information when the input A is a bitmap image that is outputting `574 x 495` as output image size ?

Comment: @Divakar A is a 800 x 800 uint8 and 640 000 bytes after I turned the initial image of 800 x 800 x 3 uint8 to 800 x 800 with `rgb2gray`.

Comment: @Sarahdata could you add the original image (may be as an edit to the question)? I guess you have enough rep to upload a picture

Comment: [https://www.dropbox.com/s/a7zkuyci2phwqir/4.png?dl=0] I think this should work...

Comment: I read your edit. Now the figure looks like it should look like AND its size in BMP format is  400x400 ! When I save as on the matlab figure, it still gives me a 574 x 495 size but I guess this is just not the right way to save figure. And I guess I should have convert the double image in uint8. Thank you all !

Answer (score 3):

Let `A` denote your matrix and

```
m = 2; %// block size: rows
n = 2; %// block size: columns
```

### Method 1

Use [`blockproc`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/blockproc.html):

```
B = blockproc(A, [m n], @(x) mean(x.data(:)));
```

Example:

```
>> A = magic(6)
A =
    35     1     6    26    19    24
     3    32     7    21    23    25
    31     9     2    22    27    20
     8    28    33    17    10    15
    30     5    34    12    14    16
     4    36    29    13    18    11
>> B = blockproc(A, [m n], @(x) mean(x.data(:)))
B =
   17.7500   15.0000   22.7500
   19.0000   18.5000   18.0000
   18.7500   22.0000   14.7500
```

### Method 2

If you prefer the reshaping way (which is probably faster), use [this great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20337173/2586922) to organize the matrix into 2x2 blocks tiled along the third dimension, average along the first two dimensions, and reshape the result:

```
T = permute(reshape(permute(reshape(A, size(A, 1), n, []), [2 1 3]), n, m, []), [2 1 3]);
B = reshape(mean(mean(T,1),2), size(A,1)/m, size(A,2)/n);
```

### Method 3

Apply a 2D convolution ([`conv2`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/conv2.html)) and then downsample. The convolution computes more entries than are really necessary (hence the downsampling), but on the other hand it can be done [separably](http://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/2006/10/04/separable-convolution/), which helps speed things up:

```
B = conv2(ones(m,1)/m, ones(1,n)/n ,A,'same');
B = B(m-1:m:end ,n-1:n:end);
```

Comment: Method 1 and method 2 give me the same result, a 400 x 400 variable in matlab workspace but a 1366 x 652 pixels image with I save it as BMP. My initial  wish was to get a 400 x 400 pixels image... I don't get it. In method 2, why do you apply `mean` twice ? Because we are in 2 D ?

Comment: My three methods (and the other answers) give me a 400x400 output when I use a 800x800 input. Yes, `mean` is applied twice to average along the two dimensions of each block

Answer (score 3):

One approach based on [`this solution`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26281056/3293881) using `reshape`, `sum` & `squeeze` -

```
sublen = 2; %// subset length
part1 = reshape(sum(reshape(A,sublen,[])),size(A,1)/sublen,sublen,[]);
out = squeeze(sum(part1,2))/sublen^2;
```

---

### Benchmarking

**Set #1**

Here are the runtime comparisons for the approaches listed so far for a input datasize of `800x 800` -

```
%// Input
A = rand(800,800);

%// Warm up tic/toc.
for k = 1:50000
    tic(); elapsed = toc();
end

disp('----------------------- With  RESHAPE + SUM + SQUEEZE')
tic
sublen = 2; %// subset length
part1 = reshape(sum(reshape(A,sublen,[])),size(A,1)/sublen,sublen,[]);
out = squeeze(sum(part1,2))/sublen^2;
toc, clear sublen part1 out

disp('----------------------- With  BLOCKPROC')
tic
B = blockproc(A, [2 2], @(x) mean(x.data(:))); %// [m n]
toc, clear B

disp('----------------------- With  PERMUTE + MEAN + RESHAPE')
tic
m = 2;n = 2;
T = permute(reshape(permute(reshape(A, size(A, 1), n, []),...
      [2 1 3]), n, m, []), [2 1 3]);
B = reshape(mean(mean(T,1),2), size(A,1)/m, size(A,2)/m);
toc, clear B T m n

disp('----------------------- With  CONVOLUTION')
tic
m = 2;n = 2;
B = conv2(ones(m,1)/m, ones(1,n)/n ,A,'same');
B = B(m-1:m:end ,n-1:n:end);
toc, clear m n B

disp('----------------------- With  MAT2CELL')
tic
AC = mat2cell(A, repmat(2,size(A,1)/2,1), repmat(2,size(A,2)/2,1));
out = cellfun(@(x) mean(x(:)), AC);
toc

disp('----------------------- With  IM2COL')
tic
out = reshape(mean(im2col(A,[2 2],'distinct')),size(A)./2);
toc
```

**Runtime results -**

```
----------------------- With  RESHAPE + SUM + SQUEEZE
Elapsed time is 0.004702 seconds.
----------------------- With  BLOCKPROC
Elapsed time is 6.039851 seconds.
----------------------- With  PERMUTE + MEAN + RESHAPE
Elapsed time is 0.006015 seconds.
----------------------- With  CONVOLUTION
Elapsed time is 0.002174 seconds.
----------------------- With  MAT2CELL
Elapsed time is 2.362291 seconds.
----------------------- With  IM2COL
Elapsed time is 0.239218 seconds.
```

To make the runtimes more fair, we can use a number of trials of `1000` on top of the fastest three approaches for the same input datasize of `800 x 800`, giving us -

```
----------------------- With  RESHAPE + SUM + SQUEEZE
Elapsed time is 1.264722 seconds.
----------------------- With  PERMUTE + MEAN + RESHAPE
Elapsed time is 3.986038 seconds.
----------------------- With  CONVOLUTION
Elapsed time is 1.992030 seconds.
```

**Set #2**

Here are the runtime comparisons for a larger input datasize of `10000x 10000` for the fastest three approaches -

```
----------------------- With  RESHAPE + SUM + SQUEEZE
Elapsed time is 0.158483 seconds.
----------------------- With  PERMUTE + MEAN + RESHAPE
Elapsed time is 0.589322 seconds.
----------------------- With  CONVOLUTION
Elapsed time is 0.307836 seconds.
```

Comment: Nice! And could be easily generalized to rectangular blocks

Comment: Thanks for runtime results :). Only think left is a simple `for` loop.

Comment: @SanthanSalai Don't think JIT could play any part here!

Comment: why? are there any related posts to that?

Comment: Sry, i left a typo in my 1st comment. *thing (instead of think :P). I didn't meant to say it would beat any of those already proposed solution. i meant it would be nice to know where it stands in the test :)

Comment: @SanthanSalai Well for a `2 x 2`, my gut feeling says JIT would get tired of indexing (there would be lots then!) and would give up :)

Comment: @SanthanSalai This is really embarrassing, but how do you write a for-loop to do this? Damn! Ah if some JIT lover out there posts something on  that, I would love to include that into the benchmarks, but writing a for-loop is too much of work! :)

Comment: Not a JIT lover but still tried as per your request :) check the results if that works :P

Comment: @SanthanSalai Tried it and results are just too bad for JIT, just really really bad!