# Reduce matrix by adding every n

Tags: matlab, matrix

Not sure how to explain it so here it goes as an example:

```
A=[1 0 0 1 4 4 4 4
   0 0 0 0 2 3 2 2
   0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1
   2 3 4 5 2 3 4 1 ]
```

result:

```
b=[ 1 1 13 12
    5 9 5  6];
```

Each of the elements is computed by adding a N size submatrix inside the original, in this case `N=2`.

so `b(1,1)` is `A(1,1)+A(1,2)+A(2,1)+A(2,2)`, and `b(1,4)` is `A(1,7)+A(2,7)+A(1,8)+A(2,8)`.

Visually and more clearly:

```
A=[|1 0| 0 1| 4 4| 4 4|
   |0 0| 0 0| 2 3| 2 2|
   ____________________
   |0 0| 0 0| 0 0| 0 1|
   |2 3| 4 5| 2 3| 4 1| ]
```

`b` is the sum of the elements on those squares, in this example of size 2.

I can imagine how to make it with loops, but its just feels vectorizable. Any ideas of how it could be done?

Assume that the matrix A has sizes that are multipliers of N.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have the **Image processing toolbox** [**`blockproc`**](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/blockproc.html) could be an option as well:

```
B = blockproc(A,[2 2],@(x) sum(x.data(:)))
```

Comment: @AnderBiguri - Agreed.  In fact this is the way I would have done it if this wasn't taken lol.

Comment: @AnderBiguri Agree with you. It looks elegant with one-liner. but if you see this [benchmarking](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30263964/2111163) from divakar for the other answer, `blockproc` is always the slowest. If efficiency is not a criteria for you, this one is the way to go :)

Comment: @SanthanSalai - Always code for readability first.  When you're confident and comfortable, then you can start changing for efficiency... and that's only if you can accurately measure it.  I would have started with this first... then eventually migrated to one of my answers.  All part of the process!

Comment: @SanthanSalai I agree with rayryeng here.  First readability and then efficiency. Especially for a SO answer,  I feel like this one makes more sense to future matrix reducers

Answer (score 4):

**Method 1:**

Using [`mat2cell`](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mat2cell.html) and [`cellfun`](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cellfun.html)

```
n = 2;
AC = mat2cell(A,repmat(n,size(A,1)/n,1),repmat(n,size(A,2)/n,1));
out = cellfun(@(x) sum(x(:)), AC)
```

**Method 2:**

Using [`permute`](http://in.mathworks.com/help/control/ref/permute.html) and [`reshape`](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/reshape.html)

```
n = 2;
[rows,cols] = size(A);
out = reshape(sum(sum(permute(reshape(A,n,rows/n,n,[]),[1 3 2 4]))),rows/n,[]);
```

**PS:** Here is a close [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30263583/2111163) related to this one, which you might find useful. That question is to find mean while this one is to find sum.

Comment: Nice. Using `n*ones( ... )` could also be a possible alternative to `repmat( ... )`.

Comment: @eigenchris yeah but i read it somewhere that `repmat` would be faster than the `ones` approach

Comment: Running a few tests on large matrices, it seems you are correct!

Answer (score 4):

Here are two alternative methods:

## Method #1 - `im2col`

Another method using the image processing toolbox is to use `im2col` with the `distinct` flag and sum over all of the resulting columns.  You would then need to reshape the matrix back to the right size:

```
n = 2;
B = im2col(A, [n n], 'distinct');
C = reshape(sum(B, 1), size(A,1)/n, size(A,2)/n);
```

We get for `C`:

```
>> C

C =

     1     1    13    12
     5     9     5     6
```

---

## Method #2 - `accumarray` and `kron`

We can generate an index matrix with `kron` which we can use as bins into `accumarray` and invoke `sum` as the custom function.  We would again have to reshape the matrix back to the right size:

```
n = 2;
M = reshape(1:prod([size(A,1)/n, size(A,2)/n]), size(A,1)/n, size(A,2)/n);
ind = kron(M, ones(n));
C = reshape(accumarray(ind(:), A(:), [], @sum), size(A,1)/n, size(A,2)/n);
```

Again we get for `C`:

```
C =

     1     1    13    12
     5     9     5     6
```

Comment: I am allways impressed when someone manages to use kron for something!  Nice one.